# compare the elements of an array in filter with other elements of another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, array-map

I try to display a row of 'availabilities, but I would like to exclude availability with similar values ​​to the values ​​of an element from another array' date '

start time end time and duration

1. how to compare them to the other element of the 'date' array?
2. how to compare only one specific value just the duration for example?

```js
var date: [{
      client: 'jessica',
      start: '10:00',
      end: '10:30',
      duration: 30,
    },

    {
      client: 'joe',
      start: '11:00',
      end: '12:00',
      duration: 60,

    }
  ],

  var availabilities: [{
        start: '10:00',
        end: '10:30',
        duration: 30,
      },


      {

        start: '11:00',
        end: '12:00',
        duration: 60,

      },

      {
        start: '12:00',
        end: '13:00',
        duration: 60,

      },

      {
        start: '13:00',
        end: '14:00',
        duration: 60,

      },


    ],


    {
      disponibilitie.filter(availabilities =>
        availabilities.start !== date.start &&
        availabilities.end !== date.end &&
        availabilities.duration !== date.duration).map((availabilities) => {
        return ( <option value = {
            availabilities.duration
          } >
          {
            availabilities.start
          } - {
            availabilities.end
          } </option>
        )
      })
    }
```

expected result :
{ start: '12:00', end: '13:00', duration:60,js

Answer (score 0):

1 - how to compare them to the other element of the 'date' array?

```
availabilities.filter((el) => {
  return date.some((f) => {
    return el.start === f.start && el.end === f.end && el.duration === f.duration;
  });
});
```

2- how to compare only one specific value just the duration for example?

```
availabilities.filter((el) => {
  return date.some((f) => {
    return el.duration === f.duration;
  });
});
```

You can add "!" before "date.some" if you want the not matching items.

Comment: Beside that. You can open a new question on how to implement it in react.

Comment: can i talk with you in private ? i can't show you all the syntax